# Why am I geting this error: Operator ‘&&’ cannot be applied to operands of type System.Linq.IQueryable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I’m trying to retrieve data from an entity and populate a viewModel property like this:

```
viewModel.Enrollments = db.Enrollments.Where(b => b.classDays == "Monday") && (db.Enrollments.Where(b => b.CourseID == courseID);
```

but I get a operator `&&` cannot be applied to operands of type `System.Linq.IQerable<>` error.  Can you help with a way to find all Monday class with the same ID?

I tried this:  `viewModel.Enrollments = db.Enrollments.Where(b => b.classDays == "Monday")` but I get all Mondays courses but I want to limit them to a specific courseID.

Please help!

Comment: I Dont know .Net or Linq, but isnt this really just writing a query to a db or in memory collection? If so wouldnt you put all the conditions you want in the `Where()` method, or chain some other method like `and()` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to examine your parentheses.  This code won't even compile:

```
viewModel.Enrollments = db.Enrollments.Where(b => b.classDays == "Monday")
                    && (db.Enrollments.Where(b => b.CourseID == courseID);
```

In that code you're trying to use `&&` between two calls to `.Where()`, which return an `IQueryable`.  You probably mean to use `&&` *within* the `.Where()` clause:

```
viewModel.Enrollments = db.Enrollments.Where(b => (b.classDays == "Monday")
                                               && (b.CourseID == courseID));
```

Or perhaps append a second `.Where()` clause:

```
viewModel.Enrollments = db.Enrollments.Where(b => b.classDays == "Monday")
                                      .Where(b => b.CourseID == courseID);
```

Note that `.Where()` can be chained indefinitely, essentially resulting in applying each clause in turn in an `AND` fashion in the resulting query.

Comment: Thank you so much David.  That totally did it!!! It was the chaining of the Where clauses.  I spent 2 days trying different methods.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

&& Operator should be used with conditions inside where NOT with sets of enrollments (in your case)

Try This:

```
viewModel.Enrollments = db.Enrollments.Where(b => (b.classDays == "Monday") && (b.CourseID == courseID));
```